# How can i destroy my main loop and create a new one from another window in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout, tkinter-menu

I Have a signin form and after signing in I created a tray and hide signing form ...how can I destroy my old master and create a new one from tray.py?

for eg:- i have a file main.py in which I am showing form like -

```
import tkinter as tk

from signin import Signin

root = tk.Tk()


def main():
   signin = Signin(root)
   signin.show_form()
   root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

**here self.master is root of main.py**

from signin.py I click on button signing to create tray -

```
def authenticate(self):
        self.master.withdraw()
        Tray(self.master)
```

after clicking authentication button tray is created and from tray I click signout than I want to so something like from tray.py -

```
def sign_out(self):
        self.master.destroy()


        from main import root
        import signin

        signin = signin.Signin(root)
        signin.show_form()
        root.mainloop()
```

can anyone help me out to get solution for this